# After upgrading to Rails 6, getting ARgumentError on has-many-through associations

Tags: associations, upgrade, ruby-on-rails-6, has-many-through

I’m using Rails 6.0.4.4 with Ruby 2.5.7.  How do I construct a has-many-through association?  I have these models with accompanying associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles_users
  has_many :roles, through: :roles_users


class RolesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles_users
```

But when I try and query the “has-many-through” association in the console, I get this argumenterzror …

```
> u = User.first
…
> u.roles
Traceback (most recent call last):
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2))
```

This worked fine when I was on Rails 4.2.  What’s the proper way to set up a has-many-through in newer Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your ransack gem version please ?

If it's 2.0 >, you have to update it